# Best operating system abstraction?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, abstract

I'm looking for something to abstract the standard operating system functionality in C/C++: span/kill a thread, send/receive a message, start/stop a timer, maybe even memory management, although I can probably handle that myself with my own buffer pool.

I want to to be able to develop and unit test on Linux/windows and then recompile the c/c++ code for various target O/Ses (for embedded systems: eCos, FreeRTOS, VxWorks, etc)

Something as "light" as possible would be best, hopefully just a library, maybe even a collection of macros.

Comment: There is no C/C++. Answers for pure C will be quite different than answers for C++. You'll get more useful answers if you ask about the language you want, not about distant cousins.

Comment: What do you mean by "send/receive a message"? And how should it do memory management?

Answer (score 7):

Have you looked at [the Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0)?  It has threads, timers, memory management, and a signals library.

The library is not a small *download*, but most of the library components are header-only implementations (though the OS abstraction libraries tend to have to be linked), and you only have to use what you need.

Comment: errmmm yes/no (sound better in German ... J...ein (segue from Ja to Nein))

I tried to look at Boost, but was overwhelmed (which might be why I am looking for a lean,mean/thin solution)

If you can assure me that it can do that basic o/s functionality (pan/kill a thread, send/receive a message, start/stop a timer, maybe even memory management) on a host PC running Linux/windows/mac bsd, and that it can also generate (lean & efficient) code for embedded systems, then you have convinced me. I was almost convinced before, but didn't have enough time to dig into it and be sure ....

Thanks

Comment: I also support Boost as a very good option to abstract OS basic mechanishm

Take a look to Interprocess, Thread and ASIO library

Comment: There are Boost libraries for threads (Boost Thread), interprocess messaging (Boost Interprocess), and timers (Boost Timer).  Memory management is a rather broad topic, but Boost has various containers and smart pointers for memory management.  It will definitely compile and run on Linux, Windows, Mac OSX, and BSD.  It will probably run on a lot of embedded OSes.  As for whether the libraries are lean and efficient, it all depends on how you define "lean" and "efficient."

Comment: Boost is beginning to look very good ... thanks, all

Answer (score 3):

I keep a (long) list of [OS Abstraction Libraries](http://jc-bell.com/contributions/os-abstraction-libs). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you directly call only [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) functions (POSIX1 seems to fill all your needs) and install a POSIX layer above non-compliant operating system (to be read as Microsoft Windows)?

Comment: Microsoft Windows has been POSIX compliant since NT, it just returned the equivalent of 'not implemented' for every function where that's an option; unfortunately POSIX allows that for so many functions that being POSIX compliant doesn't necessarily mean usable, hence the need for a compatibility layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think boost is worth to look into; it can provide you an os abstraction, but also a compiler independence, and much, much more. It does require C++ of course. Other options: Posix.

In your list:
eCos,  VxWorks, Linux : good posix support, so you can use this.
freertos: see [link](http://www.opencircuits.com/Freertos_posix_Development)

Windows lacks good posix support out of the box (see [wikipedia Posix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX_for_Windows))
If cygwin is ok for you, you can propably use it. If you need to mix with Visual Studio, a library like boost seems more interesting (you'd abstract away from it)